# Printing jmap output for Heroku java application launched by a shell script

Tags: java, heroku, jmap

I want to log my Java application's jmap histogram periodically and this [Heroku Dev page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues#generating-heap-dumps) describes how to get jmap histos for a Heroku Java app by prefixing java command with `with_jmap`.

However, what if I'm launching my Java app with a shell script and I don't want to modify that shell script? I don't see much documentation for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own `with_jmap` script and add it to your project, if you know how to find the PID of the underlying Java process. The source for the script is here:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common/blob/master/opt/with_jmap

I'm not sure if there is a good way to do this other than some `ps ... | grep ...` command.

**EDIT**

Based on this discussion, the `with_jmap` command has been improved to support shell scripts. So you should be able to set your Procfile thusly:

```
web: with_jmap sh start.sh
```

And replace `sh start.sh` with your script, a Java command, or any other command that launches a Java process.

Comment: This certainly helps but I thought Heroku should give more flexibility for this, specially because many people might use the launchers generated by Gradle/Maven to launch the Java app.

Comment: @Buchi can you file a support ticket with Heroku asking this question http://help.heroku.com (i work there and it will be forwarded to me). I think this is a valid case, but it hasn't come up very often. And it's something i'd like to support, so a ticket would help move that along. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku recently released ps:exec in beta. Have a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-exec#using-java-debugging-tools